# Sendgrid webhook verification fails always

Tags: twilio, webhooks, sendgrid, ecdsa, sendgrid-api-v3

I cannot get the Sendgrid public key verification to work in my application. I already have all the prerequisites configured. (API key is added, Signed webhook is enabled etc)

This is my approach to test the webhook.

1. I register a [webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) url as the webhook in Sendgrid
2. I invoke the webhook from Sendgrid so that I get the call to webook.site
3. I export the request received to webhook.site as a Curl.
4. I import it into Postman
5. In Postman, I change the URL to a one from a backend service that is running in my localhost and invoke the call from Postman.

Here is my code to verify the signature. This is a exact copy of what Sendgrid has provided [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/tree/main/src/main/java/com/sendgrid/helpers/eventwebhook).

```
public boolean VerifySignature(ECPublicKey publicKey, byte[] payload, String signature, String timestamp)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, IOException {

    // prepend the payload with the timestamp
    final ByteArrayOutputStream payloadWithTimestamp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    payloadWithTimestamp.write(timestamp.getBytes());
    payloadWithTimestamp.write(payload);

    // create the signature object
    final Signature signatureObject = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
    signatureObject.initVerify(publicKey);
    signatureObject.update(payloadWithTimestamp.toByteArray());

    // decode the signature
    final byte[] signatureInBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

    // verify the signature
    return signatureObject.verify(signatureInBytes);
}
```

Now this method always returns false when it is called from below controller method.

```
    @PostMapping("/sendgrid-callback")
public boolean acceptSendgridCallback(
        @RequestBody String rawData,
        @RequestHeader("X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp") String timestamp,
        @RequestHeader("X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature") String signature
) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException, IOException, InvalidKeyException {

    System.out.println("Req body = \n" + rawData);

    ECPublicKey ecdsaKey = eventWebhook.ConvertPublicKeyToECDSA
            ("public key taken from sendgrid");

    boolean b = eventWebhook.VerifySignature(ecdsaKey, rawData, signature, timestamp);
    return b;
}
```

I am unable to find the cause for that honestly.

Can someone help here.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the `\r\n` with the request body to pass the verification if you are testing using unit test or your own http request. You don't need to add that if you are testing using actual sendgrid webhook request.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As this is a primarily a Q/A site, you are far more likely to get a response to your query about Unix system equivalent if you post your own question. You can put a link to this question/answer there. If you do get an answer here (likely in comments or an edit to the OP's question), you should still consider posting a separate question and answer. Having questions inside your answer unfortunately risks getting the post deleted.

Answer (score 1):

When I use a tool like Postman to call my webhook server I need to modify the \r\n in the payload I receive, but when in production I seem to be able to use the payload without any modification.
This code, in Ruby, works for me in both cases:

```
payload_for_verification = payload.split("},\n{").join("},\r\n{").chomp + "\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [a helper util](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/blob/main/src/main/java/com/sendgrid/helpers/eventwebhook/EventWebhook.java) from sendgrid for Java.

I have modified it a little bit.

```java
public class SendgridUtils {

    // Assuming publicKeyStr is the base64-encoded public key


    public static java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey ConvertPublicKeyToECDSA(String publicKey)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        byte[] publicKeyInBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
        return (ECPublicKey) factory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyInBytes));
    }


    /**
     * Verify signed event webhook requests.
     *
     * @param publicKey: elliptic curve public key
     * @param payload:   event payload string in the request body
     * @param signature: value obtained from the
     *                   'X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature' header
     * @param timestamp: value obtained from the
     *                   'X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp' header
     * @return true or false if signature is valid
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws NoSuchProviderException
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws SignatureException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static boolean VerifySignature(ECPublicKey publicKey, String payload, String signature, String timestamp)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, IOException {
        return VerifySignature(publicKey, payload.getBytes(), signature, timestamp);
    }

    /**
     * Verify signed event webhook requests.
     *
     * @param publicKey: elliptic curve public key
     * @param payload:   event payload bytes in the request body
     * @param signature: value obtained from the
     *                   'X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature' header
     * @param timestamp: value obtained from the
     *                   'X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp' header
     * @return true or false if signature is valid
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws NoSuchProviderException
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws SignatureException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static boolean VerifySignature(ECPublicKey publicKey, byte[] payload, String signature, String timestamp)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, IOException, IOException {

        // prepend the payload with the timestamp
        final ByteArrayOutputStream payloadWithTimestamp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        payloadWithTimestamp.write(timestamp.getBytes());
        payloadWithTimestamp.write(payload);

        // create the signature object
        final Signature signatureObject = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
        signatureObject.initVerify(publicKey);
        signatureObject.update(payloadWithTimestamp.toByteArray());

        // decode the signature
        final byte[] signatureInBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

        // verify the signature
        return signatureObject.verify(signatureInBytes);
    }

}
```

publicKey you can get from https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings > Signed Event Webhook Requests
in Verification Key

Answer (score 0):

With swagger/postman and C#

var payloadForVerification = payloadForVerification = body.Replace("},\n{", "},\r\n{").Trim() + "\r\n";

var validator = new SendGridWebHookRequestValidator();

var isValidSignature = validator.IsValidSignature(payloadForVerification, publicKey, sign, timestamp);